# Chrome Extension content_script at both document_start and document_end

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Good day to everyone, as you can see I'm pretty new at Chrome extensions.

Can you run a script from `content_scripts` before and after the the DOM or page fully loads?

Like:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
    "matches": ["<all_url>"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "run_at": "document_end"
} ]
```

Or something like:

```
 "content_scripts": [ {
    "matches": ["<all_url>"],
    "js": ["content1.js"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_start"
} ],
"content_scripts": [ {
    "matches": ["<all_url>"],
    "js": ["content2.js"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_end"
} ]
```

Comment: i want it to be before the page and after, any method will be fine.

Comment: I mean when after and before the page fully loaded.

Comment: An important note: there is no general "all DOM is loaded now" state you can detect if the page dynamically creates more DOM (e.g. infinite scroll). This needs to be dealt with [different techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener). `document_end` (or `document_idle`) guarantees only that all static DOM has been parsed.

Comment: Xan, well for that case I run a script that run indefinitely. Well my only concern was to run a two different script before and after the page loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have only one `content_scripts` entry, so it would be like:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content1.js"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_start"
  },{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content2.js"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_end"
}]
```

With this setting, `content1.js` would run at the beginning and `content2.js` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You are going in the right direction:
You can use the [run_at](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time) property, but your manifest needs to look something like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
    "matches": ["<all_url>"],
    "js": ["content1.js"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_start"
},
{
    "matches": ["<all_url>"],
    "js": ["content2.js"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_end"
}]
```

It should be an array of objects defining all content scripts instead to declaring the `content_script` property twice.

---

If you are using jQuery you can also use `$(document).ready()` like this:

```
const func1 = params => {
    // Stuff that will happen as soon as it can
};

$(document).ready(() => {
    // stuff that will happen when DOM is ready
});
```

If you are not using jQuery you can just do a quick google search to find alternatives for `$(document).ready` in vanilla js.

---

Other solution you can use it to inject content script programmatically from background script using `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` [docs](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).

Comment: This is also correct, Thanks, cannot vote up yet, and the other guy answered earlier.

Comment: I think you need 15 rep to vote up, you will get that soon.

Comment: `func1` code will not run unless you explicitly call it, like `func1()`